# No match for operator > when using with a function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have overloaded the following greater than operator:

```
bool operator > (Person & a, Person & b)
{
   //firstname is a string data type
   return (a.FirstName > b.FirstName);      
}
```

Which works fine if I have something like the following:

```
Person a = myPersonA;
Person b = myPersonB;

return myPersonA > myPersonB;
```

However, within my `Person` class I have defined a `Person getByID(int id)` function, which returns an instance of a Person, by the given ID. If I try to use my operator with the returned values from this function like this:

```
bool whosGreater = listPeople.getById(1) > listPeople.getById(2);
```

I get `"Error: no match for operator >(Person&, Person&)"`

but if I do the following it works fine:

```
Person a = listPeople.getById(1);
Person b = listPeople.getById(2);
bool whosGreater = a > b;
```

Is there something I am not seeing here? It seems to me it should work.

PS: This is for a homework, so I could really get away with declaring the variables and assign them what the functions return and get away with it, but I would like to know what is happening so that I can learn. I have tried googling it, but I can't come up with the right question.

Comment: Interesting.  In C# this would have worked.  C++ must explicitly require you to declare the "box" into which the returned Person is to be placed; in C#, that box would exist implicitly, but it would also be garbage collected automatically when it is no longer needed.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering the same thing. I could do that with any .Net language and other scripting languages. C++ is very different, and the errors are not as descriptive as I would like them to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The returned value from a function is a temporary value, not a "normal" Person object. Temporary values can only be passed in as const parameter references, so changing your parameters to `const` references should work well;

```
bool operator > (const Person & a, const Person & b)
{
   //firstname is a string data type
   return (a.FirstName > b.FirstName);      
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. There are other programming languages that allow this behavior, even though the returned value is still temporal. I have so much to learn.

Answer (score 5):

Make it:

```
bool operator > (Person const & a, Person const & b)
{
   //firstname is a string data type
   return (a.FirstName > b.FirstName);      
}
```

Normal references cannot bind to temporary objects (as the one returned by getById()). And you are not mutating passed in objects, so make the references const.